# Ordem dos comandos no robots.txt

Tags: html, seo, robots.txt

Olá, encontrei um arquivo `robots.txt` com a seguintes diretivas dentro do arquivo

---

```
User-agent: Googlebot

Allow: *

User-agent: Bingbot

Allow: *

User-agent: facebot

Allow: *

User-agent: *

Disallow: /
```

---

Minha pergunta é, o último comando de disallow não vai cancelar todos os anteriores?

Answer (score 3):

Não vai bloquear, as regras não são necessariamente "em ordem", as regras com o "nome" citado tem "preferência" sobre *um wildcard/curinga* (`*`), como no próprio exemplo do suporte google:

- https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=pt-BR

> **Permitir acesso a um único rastreador**
>
> ```
> User-agent: Googlebot-news
> Allow: /
>
> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /
> ```

---

> **Permitir acesso a todos os rastreadores, exceto um deles**
>
> ```
> User-agent: Unnecessarybot
> Disallow: /
>
> User-agent: *
> Allow: /
> ```

---

Outra situação que deve notar, é que o uso de um asterisco (`*`), corresponderá a todos os rastreadores, exceto aos diversos rastreadores [*Google AdsBot*](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943), que precisam ser nomeados explicitamente

Comment: Eu achava que p `Disallow: /` negava o acesso a todos os diretórios internos, tipo publicHTML contina com acesso, mas publicHTML/configuration o bot não teria acesso. Tipo que o bot só enxergaria o que está na raiz, e não as pastas dentro do diretório... Mas acho que eu estava achando errado rss

Comment: @hugocsl isso sim, bloqueia todos, mas na "ordem", o "allow 'explicito'" aparentemente dá preferencia ao BOT "nomeado", mas depende de como vai escrever, no caso revisei a resposta é `um wildcard` e não `o wildcard`, logo talvez em breve eu precise reformular melhor a resposta para detalhar exemplos que sobreescreveriam, mas preciso ter certeza de tudo, pq só me tive a base os textos do suporte google, e talvez tenha "perdido" algo, além do que preciso complementar.